# How to change an image field to a certain fid programatically?

Tags: 7, entities, media

Specifically, every time a comment is saved, I'd like to programatically change a comment field 'Picture' to an image field from the user who wrote the comment. I have the following custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_comment_presave($comment) {
    $user = user_load($comment->uid);
    $uid = $user->uid;

    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['fid'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['fid'];
}
```

This doesn't work correctly, because the `field_picture_alt`, `field_picture_width`, `field_picture_title` and `field_picture_height` columns in my database don't get a value (they're `NULL`).

I've also tried

```
function MYMODULE_comment_presave($comment) {
    $user = user_load($comment->uid);
    $uid = $user->uid;

    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['fid'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['fid'];
    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['width'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['width'];
    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['height'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['height'];
    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['alt'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['alt'];
    $comment->field_picture['und'][0]['title'] = $user->field_picture['und'][0]['title'];
}
```

and that works perfectly.

However, I was wondering whether I always have to set the 'alt', 'title', 'width' and 'height' values manually as above.

Is there another faster way to inherit these caracteristics from the referred image? Can I for example inherit the 'height' and 'width' from an image style?

Comment: For nodes, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/101728/how-can-i-change-an-image-field-programatically shows a way to do it; perhaps it can be modified to work with comments

Comment: @Jimajamma: Yeah, that was one of my previous questions. However, in this case it seems unnecessary to me to save the image again, because it's already in the database. I can't imagine that it's impossible to use it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the comment tpl file. Add something like this:

```
$img_array = array(
    'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
    'path' => $user->field_picture['und'][0]['uri'],
    'width' => '',
    'height' => '',
    'alt' => $user->field_picture['und'][0]['alt'],
    'title' => $user->field_picture['und'][0]['title'],
  );

$img = theme('image_style', $img_array);
```

You can then add `<?php print $img; ?>` where you want the image to appear.

Comment: Since files are stored in the server file system in addition to the db, they work somewhat differently from other fields. You can read about the drupal file api here: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file